# Git Corrupt File Fix

Tags: php, git, apache, corrupt

The error on my server says 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL'. I receive this error after merging this specific file with someone else working on that file. It seems the error unexpected T_SL refers to bitwise operators <<. Now I am certain this has to do with the merge and looking at the git repo I dont see '<<' on that line. I have had this error long time ago and found out file was corrupted but dont remember the fix. Any help is good.

Comment: You had a *merge conflict*. You need to go into the file in your working copy, resolve the conflict, and `git commit` the results.

Comment: there is no merge conflict. the file has already been pushed

Answer (score 0):

If you already pushed the content, it's likely that the pattern `<<` that you identified as *bitwise operators* is actually the git notation of a merge conflict (what [Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383402/borealid) tried to tell you with his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299251/git-corrupt-file-fix/9299609#comment11728403_9299251)).

If this was pushed, the conflict that occurred before wasn't solved correctly (and somebody pushed something without checking that it is at least working without major errors first).

An example for a marked conflict (and also help for resolving conflicts) could be found in the [git manual](http://kernel.mirrors.pair.com/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge):

> `<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt`
>   `Hello world`
>    `=======`
>    `Goodbye`
>    `>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt`

This could be read that way:

- there's a conflict in file `file.txt`
- in revision `HEAD`, the line says `Hello World`
- in revision `77976da`, the line says `Goodbye`

Now, it's your task to decide which shall be used.

The accepted answer to the question [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git) also points to the git manual, so it seems to be worth a read. But also the other answers to the referenced question have numerous hints for how to deal with merge conflicts.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3407920/520162), to keep `Hello World`, tell git to

```
git checkout --ours file.txt
```

to keep `Goodbye` instead use

```
git checkout --theirs file.txt
```

Comment: yes this i understand. i have pushed incorrect merge and looking at the file and line number the pattern << is not visible and both my local and the pushed are now the same. I'll post the solution when i have an answer